# tableviewの選択したセルを遷移先画面に表示する

Tags: swift, xcode

初心者です。
画像の様に、tableviewの選択したセルを遷移先の画面ラベルに表示する機能を実装したいのですが、
アプリをビルドしセルを選択すると、tableviewcontrollerのprepareメソッドで
 Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
とエラーメッセージが表示されます。
この文を調べ、数時間コードと格闘したのですが結局よくわかりませんでした。。

自分では原因はtableviewcontrollerのprepareメソッド、viewcontrollerの、var data:Stringの記述だと思っています。

正しいコードに直すとしたらどこをどう直すのか、ご教授願いたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ソースコードは画像としてではなく、なるべく文字で入力するようにしてください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 修正.1

`prepare()` 関数のタイミングではまだ次の画面のラベルは生成されていません。ラベルにテキストをセットしようとすると `nil` の入ったオプショナル型の `label` を強制的にアンラップしようとしてエラーになります。ここでは `viewContoller.data` に文字列をセットするのが正しいです。また、遷移先のビューコントローラもこの先必ずしも `ViewController` 型とは限らないので、オプショナルバインディング（`if let` 文）が望ましいです。

```
// TableViewController.swift

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        let data = self.dataList[indexPath.row]
        if let viewController = segue.destination as? ViewController {
            // viewController.label.text = data
            viewController.data = data
        }
    }
}
```

#### 修正.2

現在の動作ではエラーになりませんが、`ViewController` のプロパティ `var data: String!` に値が入る保証がないので、なるべくなら `String?` にすべきです。`viewDidLoad()` 関数内ではオプショナルバインディングで値の存在を確認した上でラベルへ反映します。

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    // var data: String!
    var data: String?
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let data = self.data {
            self.label.text = data
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！お教えいただいた様に修正しましたところ問題なく動きました。オプショナルバインディングを使うタイミングをもっと知る必要がありますね、、

Comment: そうですね。あと今回のエラーの直接の原因は、次の画面のラベルが生成される前に、そのラベルへテキストをセットしようとしたことなので、ビューコントローラのライフサイクルを学ぶ必要がありますね

Comment: なるほど、、ライフサイクルのことについてもしっかり調べてみます。

Comment: 有益なご助言、本当にありがたいです！

Comment: どもでした。解決でしたらベストアンサーか質問の削除で締めてくださると助かります